# How to assign an item from a list of items to a new object by value?

Tags: c#, list

In my application I have a list of 'PortalItemTag' objects.  A PortalItemTag associates a Portal, Item and Tag together.  I've been asked to take the PortalItemTagTypeId that belongs to each PortalItemTag object and to copy the value to the PortalItemTagTypeId property on the Tag object.

For reference, a PortalItemTag object is comprised of a Portal object, an Item object, a Tag object and a few additional properties.

As I went through assigning each property to the Tag I realized that my list of Tags are assigned to the PortalItems by reference.  The first line of code inside the foreach loop performs this operation.

Instead of creating a reference to the Tag object i'd like a new instance of the Tag object assigned.  Is there an easy way to do this?

```
        foreach (var portalItemTag in portalItemTags)
        {
            var tag = _tags.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == portalItemTag.TagId);

            portalItemTag.Tag = tag; 

            if (portalItemTag.Tag != null)
                portalItemTag.Tag.PortalItemTagTypeId = portalItemTag.PortalItemTagTypeId;
        }
```

After exiting the above loop I would like to see two records with the same tag, but different PortalItemTagTypeId's.

```
PortalItemTag - Object 1
PortalId: 1
ItemId: 1
PortalItemTagTypeId: 1
Tag:
{
Id:1
Name: Sample Tag
PortalItemTagTypeId:1
}

PortalItemTag - Object 2
PortalId: 1
ItemId: 1
PortalItemTagTypeId: 2
Tag:
{
Id:1
Name: Sample Tag
PortalItemTagTypeId:2
}
```

However, at the moment the last assignment wins because I am referencing the Tag object and changing he PortalItemTagTypeId on the referenced object which changes it for both PortalItemTags.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how this might be accomplished without much pain?  I'm trying to avoid implementing a 'Clone()' method but will do so if it's the only way...

Thanks in advance!

Edited sample objects for clarity.

Comment: What is `_tags` in the code above?

Comment: You state that you want to "take the `PortalItemTagTypeId` that belongs to each `PortalItemTag` object and to copy the value to the `PortalItemTagTypeId` property on the `Tag` object", yet your example `PortalItemTag` objects do not have a separate `PortalItemTagTypeId` property.

Comment: _tags is a list of Tags.  Each tag has an Id and a What column.

Comment: @RufusL I've added the property to each sample object.  I forgot to put it on the parent in the example.  Thank you for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to update the `portalItemTag.PortalItemTagTypeId` and add a new `Tag` with the same values to the `portalItemTag` object?

This should work:

```
foreach (var portalItemTag in portalItemTags)
{
    // Get the tag that matches this portalItemTag.TagId
    var tag = _tags.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == portalItemTag.TagId);

    // If it's not null, copy the tag to this object 
    // and update it's PortalItemTagTypeId property
    if (tag != null)
    {
        // Create a new tag and copy the property values from the other tag to this one
        var newTag = new Tag
            {
                Id = tag.Id,
                Name = tag.Name,
                PortalItemTagTypeId = tag.PortalItemTagTypeId 
            };

        portalItemTag.PortalItemTagTypeId = tag.PortalItemTagTypeId;
        portalItemTag.Tag = newTag;
    }
}
```

If you're doing this in different places or if the properties of the Tag object may change, it might be worthwhile to implement a `Clone` method on your `Tag` class itself. It would look something like:

```
class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PortalItemTagTypeId { get; set; }

    public Tag Clone()
    {
        return new Tag { Id = Id, Name = Name, 
            PortalItemTagTypeId = PortalItemTagTypeId };
    }
}
```

Then your `foreach` code would be simplified to:

```
foreach (var portalItemTag in portalItemTags)
{
    var tag = _tags.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == portalItemTag.TagId);

    if (tag != null)
    {
        portalItemTag.PortalItemTagTypeId = tag.PortalItemTagTypeId;
        portalItemTag.Tag = tag.Clone();
    }
}
```

You mentioned in your comment that you wanted to do it in one line. While it may be fun and look cool, it will be a pain for someone else to read or to debug if things go wrong, but here's one way you could do it (using the Clone method described above). Note that there are two assignments going on in this mess, the second one happens based on the result of the first one. But at a glance it looks like just a single assignment is happening:

```
foreach (var portalItemTag in portalItemTags)
{
    portalItemTag.PortalItemTagTypeId =
        (portalItemTag.Tag = _tags.Any(t => t.Id == portalItemTag.TagId)
            ? _tags.First(t => t.Id == portalItemTag.TagId).Clone()
            : default(Tag)) != default(Tag)
                ? portalItemTag.Tag.PortalItemTagTypeId
                : portalItemTag.PortalItemTagTypeId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wrote something very similar before coming back to check:

                var tempTag = _tags.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id == portalItemTag.TagId);

                var tag = new Tag();
                tag.Id = tempTag.Id;
                tag.What = tempTag.What;

I was curious if there was a way of combining the two into a single linq statement; but that's a different question!

Comment: Updated answer with alternate suggestion, followed by very ugly, not recommended, one line solution.